# Sequelize findOrCreate generates two rows

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm using [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) on a Postgresql database and I run the following query:

```
let idUser = req.user.idUser;

db.table.findOrCreate( { where : { idUser : idUser }}).spread(function (data, created) {
    res.json({
        value : data.birthday
    });
});
```

Given that I'm using findOrCreate, I would expect that the first time I run this on a new user, it tries to find a value in table, doesn't find it and creates a row. Any subsequent time it runs, it will find and use that row.

However, around **65% of the time it creates two rows for the same user!** I store when the row was created, and the value for both rows is usually within a few milliseconds of each other. Any idea on what could be causing this? And why it happens only sometimes?

My understanding was that this wouldn't be possible when using findOrCreate. I appreciate all help! Thank you

Also, what would be the equivalent in SQL to findOrCreate?

Comment: Maybe you're running 2 sequential queries and while first is inserting row, second is sure that there is no row with same data and also runs. Use transaction with isolation level to avoid it.

Comment: @TilekbekovYrysbek I thought of that but my understanding was that findOrCreate would be atomic.. How do I use isolation level?